# Open long url using ShellExecute c++

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to open an url using `ShellExecute()`.
The url is generated by my program for a long http get request, and `ShellExecute()` doesn't work and shows no responds.

```
    ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), url, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL); // Does nothing when url is too long
```

Than I wrote a batch file for the same command, and when the url length is greater than 259 characters it shows this error:

```
start "" "{mywebsite}/&&&&..." // Repeating &


Windows cannot find 
'{my-url}/{long-get-request} ....
Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

Any idea for extending the character limit for `ShellExecute()`? Or maybe a cool solution to open a long url besides `ShellExecute()` or `system()` or `System::Diagnostics::Process::Start()`, they all fail to work.

Comment: You could get the default web browser and execute it directly via `CreateProcessW`. The command line can be up to 32766 characters. In Windows 8+, one way to get a command line template for the default web browser is to call [`AssocQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773471) with the flag value `ASSOCF_ISPROTOCOL` to get the `ASSOCSTR_COMMAND` to "open" the "http" protocol. You have to substitute in the parameters in the template -- e.g. the URL string is subtituted for `"%1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion for copying the link in to *.html file will work, however `ShellExecute` will run the program associated with `*.html` not `http:`. In theory those associations can be different. If you don't care, then just find the association with `*.html` and use `CreateProcess` as follows:

```
std::wstring url = L"http://localhost/fake.php?123";
wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
DWORD size = _countof(buf);
AssocQueryString(0, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, L".html", 0, &buf[0], &size);
std::wstring cmd(buf);
cmd += L" ";
cmd += url;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si{ sizeof(si) };
CreateProcess(0, &cmd[0], 0, 0, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
...
```

In Windows 10 `ShellExecute` accepts large argument lines.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have a solution, but it's probably not the best solution. Basically, I create an html file that redirects to my long url.

```
private: Void showPage(const string& httpGetString) {
            string url = "{my-website}?" + httpGetString;
            remove("jumper.html");
            string htmlJumper = "<html><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=" + url + "\"</html>";
            fstream jumperFile;
            jumperFile.open("jumper.html", ios::out);
            jumperFile << htmlJumper;
            jumperFile.close();
            ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), L"jumper.html", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        }
```